# Difference between two seemingly identical if statements

Tags: python, math

Hi I made a script to calculate right triangles, and as a verification method, I used

```
if a != ((b*b)+(c*c))/a:
    print("Incorrect")
```

However, for triangles bigger than 134217729, 9007199388958720, 9007199388958721 this method produced false negatives. When I changed the equation to

```
if a**2 != (b**2)+(c**2):
    print("Incorrect")
```

it stopped producing false negatives. So what's the reason one of these work and the other doesn't? I used the following code to test:

```
b = 134217729
c = 9007199388958720
a = 9007199388958721

a = ((b*b)+(c*c))/a
print(a)

a = ((b**2)+(c**2))/a
print(a)

n = (b**2)+(c**2)
a = n**(1/2)
print(a)

a = 9007199388958721
if a**2 == (b**2)+(c**2):
    print("Correct")
```

And the output was:

```
9007199388958720.0
9007199388958722.0
9007199388958722.0
Correct
```

What's going on???

Comment: Equality comparisons with floating point numbers is intrinsically problematic because of round-off error. Use inequalities instead.

Comment: Try displaying intermediate values (i.e. `b*b` vs `b**2`) to get a better idea of what's going on